# Inserting an element inside a table cell in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add an element into my table by using JavaScript.

I have tried to do it using innerHTML as:

```js
cell6.innerHTML = '<input id="Holland" onclick="Ja()" type="submit" value="Wijzig">';
```

The problem is when i do this all the buttons will be the same and have the same ID. I want to have a different id for every button. It should be somthing like this:

```js
cell6.innerHTML = '<input id="+ object.capital+ " onclick="Ja()" type="submit" value="Wijzig">';
```

I tried also to make a variable with a createElement in it :

The output is given below:

`[object HTMLInputElement]` in the row instead of a button.

The JavaScript function is given below:

```js
    function loadCountries() {
       fetch("restservices/countries")
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(function(myJson) {
       var tabel = document.getElementById("mijnTabel");
       
       for (const object of myJson) {
        var rij = tabel.insertRow(1);
        rij.addEventListener("click", function() {
        showWeather(object.latitude, object.longitude, object.capital); 
        });
        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "button");
        x.setAttribute("value", "Click me");
        x.setAttribute("id", object.capital);
        var cell1 = rij.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = rij.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = rij.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = rij.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = rij.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = rij.insertCell(5);
        var cell7 = rij.insertCell(6);
        cell1.innerHTML = object.name;
        cell2.innerHTML = object.capital;
        cell3.innerHTML = object.region;
        cell4.innerHTML = object.surface;
        cell5.innerHTML = object.population;
        cell6.innerHTML = x;
        //cell6.innerHTML = '<input id="+ object.capital+ " onclick="Ja()" type="submit" value="Wijzig">';
        //cell7.innerHTML = '<input id="verwijder" onclick="Nee()" type="submit" value="Verwijder">';
       }
       });
    }
```

**HTML code:**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/l8p1.css">

    <title>Les 8 Practicum 1</title>
    <body>
     <div id="frame">
      <div id="myLocation">
       <div id="titel1">
        <h3>Mijn locatie</h3>
       </div>
       <label id="landcode" for="landcode">Landcode: </label><br> <label
        id="land" for="land">Land: </label><br> <label id="regio"
        for="regio">Regio: </label><br> <label id="stad" for="stad">Stad:
       </label><br> <label id="postcode" for="postcode">Postcode: </label><br>
       <label id="latitude" for="latitude">Latitude: </label><br> <label
        id="longitude" for="longitude">Longitude: </label><br> <label
        id="ip" for="ip">IP: </label>
      </div>
      <div id="weatherInfo">
       <div id="titel2"></div>
       <label id="temperatuur" for="Temperatuur"></label><br> <label
        id="luchtvochtigheid" for="Luchtvochtigheid"></label><br> <label
        id="windsnelheid" for="Windsnelheid"></label><br> <label
        id="windrichting" for="Windrichting"></label><br> <label
        id="zonsopgang" for="Zonsopgang"></label><br> <label
        id="zonsondergang" for="Zonsondergang"></label>
      </div>
      <div id="countryList">
       <div id="titel3">
        <h3>Beschikbare vakantiebestemmingen</h3>
       </div>
       <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table id="mijnTabel">
         <tr>
          <th>Land</th>
          <th>Hoofdstad</th>
          <th>Regio</th>
          <th>Oppervlakte</th>
          <th>Inwoners</th>
          <th>Wijzig</th>
          <th>Verwijder</th>
         </tr>
        </table>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <script src="javascript/les8_p1_functies.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Any idea how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You're dropping some quotes:

```
cell6.innerHTML = '<input id="' + object.capital + '" onclick="Ja()" type="submit" value="Wijzig">';
```

This works.

Answer (score 2):

Here im inserting a radio in a cell but you can add what you wish

```
var cell = tr.insertCell();
var radio = document.createElement("input");
radio.setAttribute("type", "radio");
cell.appendChild(radio);
```